# Using Firestore's snapshot.forEach to create a table

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to output an array filled with Firestore objects onto a table, but just displays the last object above the table

```
<table class="darkTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>List of Available Shows</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <div id="showList"></div>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  firebase.firestore().collection('TV Shows').get().then(snapshot => {

        var i = 0;
        var array = [];

        snapshot.forEach(doc => {

            array[i] = doc.data().show.name;

            //console.log(doc.data().show.name);
            //showList.innerHTML = array[i] + "<br />"; 

            showList.innerHTML = '<td>' + array[i] + '</td>';
            i++;
        });

    }); 
</script>
```

Is it the way I'm going about the td code lines?

Comment: I think you missed `+`  in `showList.innerHTML += '<td>' + array[i] + '</td>';`

Answer (score 2):

assuming this markup:

```
<div id="showList"></div>
```

then it works about like this:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('TV Shows').get().then(snapshot => {
    var showList = document.getElementById('showList');
    var html = '<table class="darkTable"><thead><tr>';

    html += '<th>List of Available Shows</th>';
    /* add further columns into here, alike the one above. */

    html += '</tr></thead><tbody>';
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        html += '<tr>';

        html += '<td>' + doc.data().show.name + '</td>';
        /* add further columns into here, alike the one above. */

        html += '</tr>';
    });
    html += '</tbody></table>';
    showList.append(html);
});
```

Comment: This actually just has all that raw code display instead

Comment: @SalimElouafi Use `showList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);` instead of `showList.append(html);`

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting the entire showList element with every iteration of the loop:

```
showList.innerHTML = '<td>' + array[i] + '</td>';
```

I suspect you mean to append to it each time instead or resetting it entirely each time.  Maybe try building a string with each iteration, then set the whole thing after the loop is over.

Comment: @MartinZeitler If showList was actually undefined at runtime, don't you think it would generate an error rather than show the last element?

Comment: within the scope of the provided script, it is `undefined`... except globally defined.